# handling non utf8 input with golang

Tags: go

i have some input of weird chars which generated by program to stdout , i want to write a go script which monitoring the stdout to replace those characters.

i did some research it seems golang only support utf8 , i am interesting on decoding those characters using UTF decode something like : https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_encode 
for example :

Ã¼  will be -> ü

is there a golang function /library which helps with this /any example appreciated

Comment: The language has some built-in support for UTF-8 encoding, but that does not limit the encodings that a Go program can use. What encoding is the input?  Show some example of the input bytes and the runes or UTF-8 you want to convert them to.

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding

Answer (score 2):

Use the text/transform package. You need to know the encoding though...

Example reading an ISO8859 format textfile:

```
import (
"golang.org/x/text/transform"
"golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
)

file,_ := os.Open("somefile.txt")
defer file.Close()

reader := transform.NewReader(file, charmap.ISO8859_15.NewDecoder())
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)
for scanner.Scan() {
    line:=scanner.Text()
    // process line
}
```